# How to run linphone-android project in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, voip, linphone

I have downloaded the source of linphone-android-master project. I want to build it and run. I have read the readme file with the source. I didn't understand things completely. I am not familiar with native programming in android. I am working on windows 8, I have downloaded Cygwin, android-ndk. Also I have android sdk with me. Can anyone please help me to run this. Please give me a step by step procedure if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Readme file has enough explanation. You just need to install dependent libraries first and then follow README file. 
run 1) ./configure 2) 
make  3)
make install

Comment: check complete guide on http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html

Comment: There a lot of fix that you must do it . Missing python modules , fix android studio bug ....

Answer (score 0):

Procedure in base is very easy (but) .

> ./prepare.py -c
>
> ./prepare.py
>
> make

***Possible fix's :***

-- uninstall python and install it again with :

brew install python@2

Then command pip will work (for me).

**Install missing modules :**

```
pip install pystache
pip install six

brew install graphviz
```

Look at last error log and install all missing modules or any other libs from logs.

**Go to :**

```
cd submodules/externals/libvpx
```

**and :**

```
git checkout .
```

Also you must use (When logs print no permission message) :

```
chmod -R 777 /SOME-FOLDER
```

etc.